# Html audio element does not load file from URL

Tags: html5-audio

I need your help.

I want to put a link of the music into the audio tag and it seems like this:

```html
<audio controls autoplay>

    <source src="http://www.boxca.com/lctj4xdqkhjr/Evgeny_Grinko_-_Вальс_.mp3.html" type="audio/mpeg">

    <source src="http://pressplayaudio.com/?artist=Evgeny-Grinko&track=Field.ogg" type="audio/ogg">

    Your browser does not support the audio element.

</audio>
```

But, it doesn't work and I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Please post some sort of error information so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to link an html website with some audio player on it, instead of referencing real audio files. This wont work.

You need to provide a reference to a physical file that you host somewhere